# SendNotifyMessage and WM_SETTINGCHANGE not working anymore? (Windows 10)

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10, pinvoke

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/de-DE/2be8b655-a3d3-4f75-8570-52ee33d6a57c/poblem-mit-policymanagement?forum=visualcsharpde

Anyone got problems too with SendyNotify
SendNotifyMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 0);

I created an Applocker Rule app just like in the above link. These changes were pushed with the method RefreshPolicyEx and send to open processes with SendNotifyMessage. I cannot recall the exact date but this worked since day one but since a few weeks / months , open processes are no longer "receiving" or "handling" this event, as applocker rules are only applying when the explorer.exe processes are getting killed etc.

Anyone experienced similar stuff? Is this a windows 10 bug or an wanted change by microsoft? I tried a thousand different ways to push my gpos to open processes (even iteraded all explorer.exe handles and send it directly) but nothing is working anymore.

Comment: You have probably been relying on undocumented implementation details and your luck has just run out

Comment: but as you can see from the above microsoft social msdn, even an official MS member posted this as an solution! Also none of this stuff is undocumented, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-settingchange

Comment: The function is documented. That it has the effect you desire doesn't seem to be in any documentation that you referred to.

Comment: it is in the first section "Applications should send WM_SETTINGCHANGE to all top-level windows when they make changes to system parameters".. GPO changes are system parameters!

Comment: So submit a bug report to MS then. Not that I agree with your interpolation of the docs mind you.